# Getting values from an Excel ADO connection to a .xlsx file

Tags: excel, vba, ado, xlsx

Hi im new to using vba and ADO and i've been stuck on how to get at or return the values from a SQL query in ADO for a while now.

I'm no pro so I've hacked together multiple examples I've seen and through testing found ways of making most of this work. From what I gather i cannot use a Jet connection and the MSDASQL connection below should work.

Essentially I have an excel file which has a reference to ADO library 6.1 and I've run the below code to connect to another .xlsx file and retrieve data from a specific sheet.

The data on the sheet will simply be two columns, one with keys and one with values. The headers are literally "Keys" and "Values" and there are 3 rows of data then below that.

Here is what I have so far but I havent been able to retrieve the values as of yet(Also I've been testing bits here and there so please ignore any unused Dims or variables, I will use them eventually in here!):

```
Function GetCredentialsTest() As Variant
Dim app As New Excel.Application, FileName As String, AlgoName As String, SRange As Variant, credentials As Variant, _
APISheetName As String

credentials = Array()
'ReDim Preserve credentials(UBound(credentials) + 4, UBound(credentials) + 4)
FileName = "c:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Storage.xlsx"
APISheetName = "-----Credentials"

Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String


DBPath = FileName

sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

Conn.Open sconnect

sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [-----Credentials$]" 

mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn
credentials = mrs.GetRows

'When I use the below Msg Box I do get 1:2-2:3 indicating the array is correctly sized I think    
MsgBox "1:" & UBound(credentials, 1) - LBound(credentials, 1) + 1 & "-" & "2:" & UBound(credentials, 2) - LBound(credentials, 2) + 1

'when I try to see an individual value though I get a subscript out of range error
MsgBox credentials(2, 2)
'ive also tried to copy directly to a sheet cell but i've had no luck
'Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs

mrs.Close
Conn.Close
GetCredentialsTest = credentials

End Function
```

Comment: If your array is (0 to 1, 0 to 2) then you can't reference (2, 2), since the first index will be out of bounds.  The second element's index in the first dimension is 1 not 2.

Comment: Yep....yep, your right @TimWilliams. I wish there wasn't a record of this fail online now, I was at a melting point and completely missed that. Thanks for spotting that and answering my question, feel free to post the answer and i'll mark as the solution